# Save picture of chart in Excel from Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm working from Access. By clicking a button in a mask I would like to open (better if not visible) an Excel file, update data source and graph, save the graph that is in a cell range into an image and send this image in the text of a mail.

The image saving `RefreshAll` method is not recognised as well as range().

```vb
Function invia_grafici_accessi()

Dim MyXL As Object
Dim Rng As Object
Dim oChrtO As Object

Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With MyXL
    .Application.Visible = False
    .Workbooks.Open "\\sdocenco01\OPC\12_SCL_RESPONSABILI_COORDINATORI\ACCESSI_SPORTELLI\grafici.xlsx"
    .Workbooks.Foglio1.RefreshAll
    
    Rng = .Workbooks.Foglio1.Range("AG15:AU116")

    Rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    lWidth = oRng.Width
    lHeight = oRng.Height

    Set oChrtO = oWs.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)

    oChrtO.Activate
    With oChrtO.Chart
        .Paste
        .Export FileName:="\myforder\myimage.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
    End With

    oChrtO.Delete
End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Some fixes/suggested changes below:

```vba
Sub invia_grafici_accessi()
    Dim MyXL As Object, wb As Object, ws As Object
    Dim Rng As Object
    Dim oChrtO As Object

    Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    MyXL.Visible = False
    'get a reference to the opened workbook
    Set wb = MyXL.Workbooks.Open("\\sdocenco01\OPC\12_SCL_RESPONSABILI_COORDINATORI\ACCESSI_SPORTELLI\grafici.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1) 'or whichever worksheet you want
    
    wb.RefreshAll 'make sure your queries are not set to run in the background...
    
    Set Rng = ws.Range("AG15:AU116")
    Rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    lWidth = Rng.Width
    lHeight = Rng.Height

    Set oChrtO = oWs.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)
    oChrtO.Activate
    With oChrtO.Chart
        .Paste
        .Export Filename:="\myfolder\myimage.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
    End With
    oChrtO.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks i guess we are getting closer... i still have an error: "ws As Worksheet" it says type defined by user not defined

Comment: I missed the late binding thing - ws should be `As Object`.  If you've not added a reference to the Excel object library then your code will not recognize `xlScreen` or `xlPicture`, so either add a reference or define those as constants in your code.  If you use `Option Explicit` then these types of issues would be flagged up for you.

Comment: yep xlscreen do not work and i cannot add a reference... what is your suggestion than... i can i define those as constants? thanks

Comment: Add `Const xlScreen = 1` and `Const xlPicture = -4147`

Comment: unfortunatelly i still have an error on the line .paste suntime 1004 (error defined by the obj)

Comment: got it  oChrtO.Activate is missing before With